Fontsize vs. Edgelength
I'm drawing my graph with:
fdp -Tjpg testgraph_4.txt > fdp_4.jpg

and the data
strict graph { 
  layout="fdp"
  splines=spline
  fontsize=12
  fontname="Source Code Pro Medium"
  k=0.0001
  len=0.0001    
  maxiter=100000
  normalize=true
  beautify=true
  
  # ... the graph data
}

The result of three consecutive runs looks like:

first run
second run
third run

a) How can I get a graph that is a little less "strechy" with better readable labels?
b) The docs for the start parameter says: If unset, the nodes are randomly placed in a unit square with the same seed is always used for the random number generator, so the initial placement is repeatable. How can I get a repeatable result when nothing is changed?

Cannot see the "result" files. Check properties, enable everyone to see, or see why there is a ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

If those files are text, just include them here, or use PasteBin if you feel they are too large/long. If the files are images, use the built-in uploaders on this site. Do not use whatever site you're using currently as it isn't working, and using unnecessary 3rd party sites is suspicious.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry for the confusion with the images. Updated the original post.

what happens if you remove the 5 lines k... thru beautify...?

Also, what OS are you using & what version of Graphviz?

Removing the five lines doesn't change much, I inserted this lines to improve the final image. I'm using Win11 and graphviz  9.0.0.

@sroush I tried Ubuntu 24.04 with  graphviz version 2.43.0, no big difference in result. Updating Win-graphviz to 12.2.0 also makes no difference.

Guessing it is a bug related to clusters.  Try creating an issue here:  https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/
